# Support for <input type='datetime'>

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dartium

Does Dartium/dart support the `<input type='datetime'>`? I am surprised to see a text box being rendered instead of a date and time UI.

Thanks

Comment: That's a chrome/chromium issue: Partial support in Chrome refers to a missing calendar widget for the "datetime" type. http://caniuse.com/input-datetime

Answer (score 1):

(Copied from comments)

As of Chrome 35; there is still no built-in calendar widget for `<input type="datetime">` :(

Strangely, Chrome for Android apparently does have this!
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime